# I would like to have range dynamically change based on new data

Tags: dynamic, excel-formula, range

I have an excel scatter plot chart that pulls data from 4 ranges.  The data is periodically renewed.  When the data is renewed, the range has to be updated.  The data that determines which of 4 ranges it falls into is a combination of two columns.  I would like to have the range dynamically change based on the new data.

The data is sorted where the ranges will be contiguous but not overlap or intermix.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what the data looks like? I would help people better provide you an answer.

Comment: The four ranges are determined by unique columns A & D.  So there will be a range where A+D = "AN", second = "SN", third = "AR" & fourth = "SR".

Comment: An example is below.  As of now, Range 1 is A1:D5, Range 2 is A6:D10, Range 3 is A11:D16 & Range 4 is A17:D24.

As the data changes, the ranges need to change depending on columns A & D.

An example is below.  Thanks,

Comment: A  B   C  D
A  $439,900   2,850  N
A  $497,551   2,866  N
A  $378,053   2,890  N
A  $419,900   2,900  N
S  $332,000   2,800  N
S  $509,584   2,832  N
S  $449,900   2,842  N
S  $381,990   2,898  N
S  $389,012   2,898  N
A  $344,000   2,836  R
A  $359,900   2,836  R
A  $335,000   2,898  R
A  $365,000   2,826  R
A  $420,000   2,829  R
A  $419,900   2,872  R
S  $293,000   2,800  R
S  $270,000   2,811  R
S  $431,700   2,813  R
S  $279,900   2,886  R
S  $320,000   2,886  R
S  $440,000   2,886  R
S  $324,900   2,890  R
S  $352,000   2,891  R

Comment: I can't paste a range so I'm not sure how to provide an example.  The data in columns B & C are what is shown in the graph.

Comment: A  B                         C          D
A  $      419,900         2,900  N
S  $      332,000         2,800  N
S  $      389,012         2,898  N
A  $      344,000         2,836  R
A  $      419,900         2,872  R
S  $      293,000         2,800  R
S  $      352,000         2,891  R